# Not able to connect mongodb to nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have installed mongoose using npm install mongoose .But when i try to run the js file its not connecting.
see my code below.

```js
const c = require('config')
const express= require('express')
const app= express()
const port=3000

const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const url = "mongodb+srv://mongouser:mongouser@cluster0.jpdno.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority"

const connectdb = async () => {
    await mongoose.connect(url)
    console.log('db connected')
}
app.listen(port,() => console.log("listening..."))
```

I am not getting any errors but after listening.. nothing is showing.
I am new to this please help me.

Comment: `const connectdb = async () => ...` You are declaring the function. But you also need to actually call it. `connectdb()`

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right path. To check whether you successfully connected to database use:

```
mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => { console.log('Successfully connected to database' });
```

Also you want to return your connection so you could use it later for database manipulation. It should look like this:

```
const connectdb = async () => {
  await mongoose.connect(url);
  
  return mongoose.connection; // Please note that you are returning reference 
}
```

Last notes, I believe async/await is redundant when dealing with mongoose inside Node.js and you should probably want to include some option argument on your connect method:

```
mongoose.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true} );
```

Now you should be good to go!